# identify end the edges of iframe using javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe which has a table structure with multiple rows and columns. I want to display tool tips when i hover over a cell. If the cell is at the right or bottom edge of the iframe, I would like to change the position of the tool tip.

I want to be able to identify that edge of iframe so that I can change its position. How to identify it using jquery or javascript?

Comment: A plugin like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) would probably make your life easier (I believe it does this already, taking in to account real-estate available when it decides on a location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

#### http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

or

#### http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

or [many more](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)

Comment: Actually was looking at non plugin based solution, but since the flow player plugin does not require us to download the plugin onto our local machine, I find it I can use that without making any performance impact of an additional javascript file.